# Compare two documents with slight differences in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two documents that are mostly the same, but with some small differences I want to ignore. Specifically, I know that one has hex values written as "0xFFFFFFFF" while the other has them just as "FFFFFFFF"

Basically, these two documents are lists of variables, their values, their location in memeory, size, etc.

But another problem is that they are not in the same order either.

I tried a few things, one being to just pack them all up in two lists of lists, and compare if the lists of lists have counterparts in each other, but with the number of variables being almost 100,000 the time it takes to do this is ridiculous (on the order of nearly an hour) so that isn't going to work. I'm not very seasonsed in python, or even the pythonic way of doing things, so I'm sorry if there is a quick and easy way to do this.

I've read a few other similar questions, but they all assume 100% identicallity, and other things that arent true in my case.

Basically, I have two .txts that have series of lines that look like:

```
***************************************
Variable: Var_name1
Size: 4
Address: 0x00FF00F0 .. 0x00FF00F3
Description: An awesome variable
..
***************************************
```

I don't care if the Descriptions are different, I just want to make sure that every variable has the same length and is in the same place, address-wise, and if they are any difference, I want to see them. I also want to be sure that every variable in one is present in the other.

And again, the address in the first one are written with the hex radix and in the second one, without the hex radix. And they are in a different order

--- Output ---

I don't really care about the output's format as long as it is human readable. Ideally, it'd be a .txt document that said something like:

```
"Var_name1 does not exist in list two"
"Var_name2 has a different size. (Size1, Size2)"
"Var_name4 is located in a different place. (Loc1, Loc2)"
```

Comment: And kind of output do you expect?

Comment: I'll add a desired output. I actually expect, once all is said and done, to have no output. I think the files should pass the test. But I need to test them anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**COMPLETE RE-EDIT**
[My initial suggestion was to use `set`s, but further discussion via the comments made me realize that that was nonsense, and that a dictionary was the real solution.]

You want a dictionary; keyed on variable name; and where the value is a list or a tuple or a nested dictionary or even an object, containing size and address. You can add each variable name to the dictionary and update the values as needed.
For comparing the addresses, a regex would do it, but you can probably get by with less overhead with just a `str.contains(_)`.

Comment: Pack the lists into sets? Also, equivalency was stated to be "same size and address" if that is what you mean. Each variable must have the same size and address, and each file must have the same variables, basically.

Comment: Well, `my_set = set(my_list)` would do a conversion: your set would contain the elements of the list, not the list itself as an (only) element. But you said that you're packing your items into lists, so you don't necessarily need to create the set *via* lists. `my_set = set()` creates a new empty set, and then however you're getting the elements that you now put in a list just `set.add(item)` instead.

Comment: Then this won't really help. Unless, maybe I make a class called "Variable" and give it attributes like "name" and "size" and "address" and then pack the sets full of these classes and then compare from there, but I'm not sure if that will work, or how that will work.

Comment: How are you comparing items when they're in lists? You're right, a set won't actually make comparing these any easier. How about a dictionary, keyed on variable name. And the value for each key would be the size and address either as a tuple or as a nested dictionary with keys of "size" and "address". Lookup and comparison between dictionaries is about(?) as fast as with sets.

Comment: I see, that's an idea. CanI  make a dictionary, give it a key, and then later change what the key points to? Like each new variable name is a key to an empty list, or something like ["","",""] and then later change it to ["4","FF00FF00","FF00FF03"] ? Or do I need to hold onto the variable name, and make the list, and then insert them together into the dictionary all at once?

Comment: That would work just fine. Once you have a unique key in the dictionary you can change it value as you please with `my_dict["key1"] = list(1,2,3)`. The only thing to watch out for is: if the value is a list, then be very careful that you are *modifying* the list later, rather than replacing it (unless you are replacing it with an updated list).